# How to query the front and back n rows of a piece of random row in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

After selecting a random row, I want to be able to select n number of records preceding and following it.
example:

```
id  content
1    add 
2    bob
3    cdf
4    asd
```

random row id is 3,i need select result:

```
2    bob
3    cdf
4    asd
```